# Mutt: apply command to all tagged messages

Tags: mutt

From the [mutt manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual.html#toc4.3):

> Once you have tagged the desired messages, you can use the `tag-prefix` operator, which is the `;` (semicolon) key by default. When the `tag-prefix` operator is used, the next operation will be applied to all tagged messages if that operation can be used in that manner.

But it seems that **I can only execute commands that are already bound to a specific keyboard shortcut**.  For example I can use `;d` to delete all selected messages.

What if I want to apply an "unbound" command (such as `purge-message`)?

I have also tried using something based on `:exec tag-prefix` or `:push tag-prefix` without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My copy of mutt doesn't have a `purge-message` function, none of the unbound
index functions look useful to use on tagged messages. But, for testing I
removed the binding for the `flag-message` function.

With that done, either of the following commands worked for me.

```
:exec tag-prefix flag-message
:push <tag-prefix><flag-message>
```

My version is reported as `Mutt 1.5.21 (2011-07-01)`

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I was doing something wrong with spaces and angle brackets in the `exec` and `push` commands.  Btw. the purge-message is related to the "trash folder patch".